# How would I go about requesting xml file data in AS3 for an iphone app?

Tags: actionscript-3

How would I set about loading an xml data file inside an AS3 application for iphone? Will there be a cross-domain issue for requesting data files from the device?

Comment: Once I have my developer key I can start testing.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but I don't believe you have access to the iOS application bundle from within your AS3 application.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, packaging local files and retrieving files from webservers is possible without domain restriction as the iOS and Adobe Air runtime environments play in their own sandbox. I used the URLLoader methods of the flash.net class:

[See Adobe AS3 URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary)